# How to check if DOM node is animating in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, dom, jquery-events

I have DOM node and click handler and I need to disable the action while animating. How can I check if element is currently being animated by a jQuery animation?

```
$('div').on('click', '.item', function() {
    if (/* this not animating */) {
        animate($(this));
    }
});
```

Do I need to set `data('play')` on that element that will be clear when finished or there is better way.

Comment: When you say "animating", are you referring to jQuery animations or to CSS transitions?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi jQuery animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
$('div').on('click', '.item', function() {
    $this = $(this); // cached so we don't wrap the same jquery object twice
    if (!$this.is(':animated')) {
        animate($this);
    }
});
```

View: [animated selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/tBDL8/1/

Comment: I was searching for `:animating` in api.jquery.com

Comment: Yea that might seem to make more sense as you are checking if it is currently "animating" rather than if it has animated, but I suppose with animated they mean it is in an animated state.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
$(element).is(":animated");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an element is animating by using the `:animated` selector.

```
if($(this).is(":animated")) { ... }
```

For more information look at: http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/